# Trouble understanding the behavior of the thread.interrupt() method

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            try { 
                Thread.sleep(99999); 
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException e) { 
                System.out.println("I'm interrupted!!"); 
            } 
         } 
    }); 

  thread.start();
  out.print(thread.isAlive()+" ");
  thread.interrupt(); 
  out.print(thread.isAlive()+" "); 
}
```

I don't understand why the console is

> true true  I'm interrupted!!

but i think the result is

> true I'm interrupted!! true

why is not the result what I think?  Thanks!

Comment: Threads run "in parallel" whenever they are not synchronized.  "In parallel" means that there is no guarantee about the order in which things will happen in different threads.  Your second thread can not possibly print "I'm interrupted" before the first thread interrupts it--that's an example of synchronization--but then your program allows that println() call and the second `thread.isAlive` println to happen _in parallel_.  I.e., there is no guarantee which of those things will happen first.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** The `Thread#interrupt()` method does not involve an `InterruptedException`  exception immediately, it merely sets an internal flag named interrupt status to `true`, this one being then checked by the impacted thread.

> The interrupt mechanism is implemented using an internal flag known as
>   the interrupt status. Invoking Thread.interrupt sets this flag. When a
>   thread checks for an interrupt by invoking the static method
>   Thread.interrupted, interrupt status is cleared. The non-static
>   Thread.isInterrupted, which is used by one thread to query the
>   interrupt status of another, does not change the interrupt status
>   flag.

So it happens some minimal delay between the set of the interrupt status, and the throwing of the `InterruptedException`, explaining why your printing `I'm interrupted!!` happens after your both calls to `Thread.isAlive()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: I notice that you are new, so if you think the answer helped you, you might validate it ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's a timing issue.

If your main thread continues and prints `thread.isAlive()` before `thread` is actually terminated, it will print `true`. You can simply check this by putting a breakpoint at the second output and wait a few moments before letting the program continue. It will print `false` for the second `isAlive` check.

Probably the output of your program will be different from time to time dependent on the context switches made between your main thread and the other thread.

Actually you can't even be sure your second thread is already sleeping at the moment you query the thread's status. If you want to make the execution order of the threads dependent on each other you will need to introduce some synchronization between the threads.

Comment: I had set a breakpoint at the second output.Exactly,second out.print shows false.Thanks for your suggestion.